# How can I perform an analysis of the NHIS imputed income variables?

Tags: stata, data

I have downloaded five family income variables from https://nhis.ipums.org/nhis-action/variables/group?id=economic_income (INCPPOINT1, INCPPOINT2, INCPPOINT3, INCPPOINT4, INCPPOINT5) for they years going from 2009 to 2018.

These variables come as imputed point estimates.

My question now is: how can I use these imputed incomes to include them in a futher regression to study the relation between health status and income via DiD?

I do not know if it possible but I would be willing to turn these variables into a single one and then use this new variable for my purpose. Basically, I need the income variable in order to know if individuals are treated or not.
If possible, how can I do it in Stata?

Of course I can also use other softwares but I'm working on Stata right now and I'm not very familiar with any other tool at the moment.